# Given a Pattern matching in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, string-matching

General format -  `"Axis(Angle),Axis(Angle),Axis(Angle)....."`

```
A = “X(90), Y(180), X(90)”
```

In the above input, I want to check whether my input A is matching with general syntax or not.

need help in Python.

I am not able to think anything

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex like [`[XYZ]\(\d{1,3}\)(,\s*[XYZ]\(\d{1,3}\))*`](https://regex101.com/r/vhuhEs/1)

It matches an axis symbol (adap the `XYZ` list) then a number of 3 digits in parenthesis, then any amount of the same thing with comma and possible space before

```py
A = "X(90), Y(180), X(90)"

if re.fullmatch("[XYZ]\(\d{1,3}\)(,\s*[XYZ]\(\d{1,3}\))*", A):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("NOK")
```